# Pass querystring parameter to second page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have web page which is passing a querystring parameter to page 2:

```
<a href="Page2.aspx?WONumber=12345">
```

On page 2 I want to have an href which passes the same parameter value to page 3.  I tried:

```
<a href="Page3.aspx?WONumber=" + request.querystring("WONumber") >
```

but that gives me a VS2008 error "attribute 'request.querystring' is not a valid attribute of element 'a'".  What should I be doing instead?

Comment: ASP.NET?    Include the language tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one (I assume ASP.NET/C#):

```
<a href='Page3.aspx?WONumber=<%=
    HttpUtility.HtmlAttributeEncode(Request.QueryString["WONumber"])%>'>Text</a>
```

Comment: Should be noted that this only works for non-server controls (do not use runat="server")

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="Page3.aspx?WONumber=<%=Request.QueryString["WONumber"] %>">link</a>
```